# Autowired service is null using AbstractITextPdfView

Tags: spring

I'm using the `AbstractITextPdfView` to display a PDF document and the autowired `operatorReportService` is always `null`:

I have checked the component scan is correct:

```
@ComponentScan("com.amci.wireless1440;com.amci.wireless1440.view")
```

I have tried using the `@Configurable` and `@Component`, and doesn't fix the issue.

```
package com.amci.wireless1440.view;

@Component
public class OperatorReportPdfView extends AbstractITextPdfView  {

    @Autowired
    OperatorReportService operatorReportService; //dependency inject

    @Override
    protected void buildPdfDocument(Map<String, Object> model,
                                    Document document, PdfWriter writer, HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // get data model which is passed by the Spring container
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Integer> assetIds = (List<Integer>) model.get("assetIds");
        String reportDate = (String)model.get("reportDate");

        //OperatorReportServiceImpl operatorReportService = new OperatorReportServiceImpl();
        operatorReportService.build(assetIds, reportDate);

    }

}

@Bean
public ViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver(
                ContentNegotiationManager manager) {

        List< ViewResolver > resolvers = new ArrayList< ViewResolver >();

        InternalResourceViewResolver r1 = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        r1.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        r1.setSuffix(".jsp");
        r1.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        resolvers.add(r1);

        //add the operator report PDF view 
        resolvers.add(pdfViewResolver());

        resolvers.add(jsonViewResolver());
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        resolver.setViewResolvers(resolvers);
        resolver.setContentNegotiationManager(manager);
        return resolver;

}

/*
 * Configure View resolver to provide IText PDF output.
*/
@Bean
public ViewResolver pdfViewResolver() {
    return new PdfViewResolver();
}
```

//From 03-07-2017///////

I added `@Configurable` to my `PdfViewResolver` class:

```
@Configurable
public class PdfViewResolver implements ViewResolver
```

I have this in my Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public OperatorReportPdfView operatorReportPdfView(){
   OperatorReportPdfView operatorReportPdfView = new OperatorReportPdfView();
   return operatorReportPdfView;
}

//Configure View resolver to provide IText PDF output.
@Bean
public ViewResolver pdfViewResolver() {
        return new PdfViewResolver();
}
```

...and my OperatorReportPdfView class configured like below:

```
@Configurable
public class OperatorReportPdfView extends AbstractITextPdfView  {
    @Autowired
    OperatorReportService operatorReportService; //dependency inject
...
}
```

In response to 3/9/2017 comment:
Thank you again very much for the help.
In my `@Configuration`class, if have:

1. `PdfViewResolver` defined as @Bean

   ```
   @Bean
   public ViewResolver pdfViewResolver() {
       return new PdfViewResolver();
   ```

   }
2. `OperatorReportPdfView` defined as `@Bean`

   ```
   @Bean
   public OperatorReportPdfView operatorReportPdfView(){
       OperatorReportPdfView operatorReportPdfView = new OperatorReportPdfView();
      return operatorReportPdfView;
   }
   ```

In the `OperatorReportPdfView` class, I'm injecting the `OperatorReportService`. I'm confident that the service can be found, because I'm injecting
it in a Controller. 
But, when I hit a breakpoint in this class, I see that the `OperatorReportService` is `null`.

```
@Component
public class OperatorReportPdfView extends AbstractITextPdfView  {

    @Autowired
    OperatorReportService operatorReportService; //dependency inject
```

3-9-2017 
Found in the console startup log:

```
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'pdfViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [com.amci.wireless1440.spring.configuration.PdfViewResolver]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Users\mspeicher\workspace-stsNEW\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Wireless1440Branch\WEB-INF\classes\com\amci\wireless1440\spring\configuration\PdfViewResolver.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=webConfig; factoryMethodName=pdfViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in com.amci.wireless1440.spring.configuration.WebConfig]
Mar 09, 2017 1:29:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'operatorReportPdfView' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [com.amci.wireless1440.view.OperatorReportPdfView]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Users\mspeicher\workspace-stsNEW\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Wireless1440Branch\WEB-INF\classes\com\amci\wireless1440\view\OperatorReportPdfView.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=webConfig; factoryMethodName=operatorReportPdfView; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in com.amci.wireless1440.spring.configuration.WebConfig]
```

Comment: How are you using the `OperatorReportPdfView`?

Comment: I'm using the OperatorReportPdfView to create an iText PDF document. I have it configured in my Configuration class as a view resolver:

Comment: 'code' public class PdfViewResolver implements ViewResolver{
 
    @Override
    public View resolveViewName(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
        OperatorReportPdfView pdfView = new OperatorReportPdfView();
        return pdfView;
    } 
     
}

Comment: You are creating new instances yourself you aren 't using the spring managed instance. Spring will only inject beans into instances it nows about.

Comment: I updated my code comments above, and not sure how to make Spring know about the OperatorReportPdfView class.

Comment: Just make it a bean and inject the dependency into your `PdfViewResolver` and let that return it.

Comment: I updated the comments above, (i.e. OperatorReportPdfView making a bean in the Configuration class). Please review my notes above. Still getting null for the service.

Comment: Making something a bean and still returning an new instance in your view resolver effectively makes your bean useless. You have to auto wire it.

Comment: Found this in the startup console and doesn't look good. Put error found above.

Comment: No it has nothing to do with that... It isn't an error. As stated you aren't using the configured bean in your PdfViewResolver. No matter how much configuration you are going to use as long as that thing is returning a new instance everything is pretty much useless.

Comment: Thank you again for all the help. I haven't been able to resolve the issue, so I changed the controller to figure out the pdfContent by calling the service  and putting the ByteArrayOutputStream in the model,... works perfectly.                             HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     // get data model which is passed by the Spring container
     ByteArrayOutputStream pdfContent = (ByteArrayOutputStream) model.get("pdfContent");

Answer (score -1):

You might need to create a @Configuration class if you don't already have one. Here's an example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean
    public OperatorReportService operatorReportService() {
        return new OperatorReportService();
    }
}
```

Make sure the this configuration class is part of your component scan.

Comment: Hello Carlos, I added the extra bean definition in my Configuration class, and the the service is still null in the OperatorReportPdfView class. I also injected the OperatorReportService in one of my controllers to verify the component scan would pick it up, and the service is not null and can be used.

Comment: I noticed in your component scan you're using a semicolon to separate the packages. Have you tried just a comma?

Comment: I replaced the semicolon with a comma, and still service is null.  All my packages start with 'com.amci.wireless1440' so it should be found ok. I added in the 'com.amci.wireless1440.view' just to see if that would fix the issue.